# Decision for category based on predicted probabilities of an ordinal logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, prediction, ordinal

Is there a simple way to decide for a category based on the predicted probabilities of an ordinal logistic regression?
In the binary case, I have so far set the criterion based on the distribution of the base data set. But this is not possible in the ordinal case.

Comment: This seems to be a stats question that'd be better suited to a site like [Cross Validated](https://www.stats.stackexchange.com) - perhaps try asking it there with some more information about your dataset.

Comment: That kind of criteria differs across methods. Different packages might set the criteria in different ways.